# How do I convert a JSONObject to a byte array and then convert this byte array to get back the original JSONObject?

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, serialization, arrays

I am using the [AWS `JSONObject` class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/util/json/JSONObject.html). Let's say I define a `JSONObject` object like so:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("Field1": 35);

JSONObject nestedObj = new JSONObject();
nestedObj.put("Name1":"value1");
nestedObj.put("Name2":42);

obj.put("Field2": nestedObj);
```

So the JSONObject looks like:

```
{"Field1": 35,
 "Field2": {"Name1": "value1",
            "Name2": 42}
}
```

I want to take this `JSONObject` and convert it to a byte array somehow:

```
byte[] objAsBytes = convertToBytes(obj);
```

where `convertToBytes` is some function that does this correctly. Then I would like to take this byte array and convert it back to the original `JSONObject` so it still preserves its original structure.

Does anyone know how to do this? I would like to do this because I am using Amazon Kinesis and more specifically the `PutRecord` API and a `PutRecordRequest` requires the data to be a `ByteBuffer`, so I need to convert the `JSONObject` to a byte array, and then wrap the byte array as a `ByteBuffer`. Then, when I retrieve the record I need to convert the `ByteBuffer` to a byte array and then get the original JSONObject.

Comment: @Pillar Sorry I'm not experienced with using `JSONObject`. Are you implying if I just represent the `JSONObject` as a String and then use the String to byte array to String conversions it should preserve the original structure of the `JSONObject`?

Comment: Yeah `JSONObject` has a `toString` method that will give you the textual `String` representation of the JSON. And it should also have a constructor that accepts a JSON `String` as an argument, converting it from text to the `JSONObject`.

Comment: JSON is just a String, so a JSONObject is nothing more than a representation of said string. If you get the byte[]  of the string, you can always create the object back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
byte[] objAsBytes = obj.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
```

I used [Json.simple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/) to try it out, seems to work!

Comment: What advantage it has over compared to base64 encoding?