# How to convert Json object to BLOB in java

Tags: java, json, rest, blob

I need to store HTTP REST API (POST, GET, PATCH, etc.) requests and responses into a database entry (Column as BLOB), so that we can audit the requests and responses later.

As part of the incoming HTTP POST request, the DTO object is coming as request body. I can extract the JSON object as a request body.

How can I convert that JSON object to BLOB in Java?

Comment: This question already has an answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947871/convert-a-string-to-a-byte-array-and-then-back-to-the-original-string and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36560223/how-do-i-convert-a-jsonobject-to-a-byte-array-and-then-convert-this-byte-array-t/36560611

Comment: This question is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400497/how-to-convert-blob-to-string-and-string-to-blob-in-java

Comment: @gbengawale He's asking for BLOB. Both your suggestions have nothing to do with blob.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String str = json.toString();
PreparedStatement ps1 = conn.prepareStatement("update table set blob=? where id=1");
Blob blob = conn.createBlob();
blob.setBytes(1, str.getBytes());
ps1.setBlob(1, blob);
ps1.executeUpdate();
```